# Full Screen Background - contain element

Tags: html, css

I have a section of a website where I need a full screen background image. I used the trick from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) - the first option. That works fine, but I have some content in that section and it is not contained. so if the height is reduced, but the width at max on a screen, the content of that section overflows. Is there any smart way of containing that content so that it reduces by height as well?

This is the CSS I'm using.

```
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/services-header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

See example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erw43u63/).
The fiddle doesn't show the result properly, here is a screenshot of what I mean. I need it to work as in the fiddle where it's contained (so that the background image expands in height even more than the current height of the browser, but in both Chrome and Mozilla, it runs out. See example [full screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/full.JPG) and [reduced](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/small.JPG).

Please help

EDIT
Here is the entire HTML

```
<div id="services-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="height: 100%;">
                <h1>
                    The Creativity of the West meet <br>
                    the Technical Skill &amp; Expertise of the East
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Our extraordinary team brings years of technology related experience to the table to ensure <br>
                    that you receive an amazing product at an unbelievable price. <br><br>
                </p>
                <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/platforms.png" alt="Platforms"> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/iphone6.png" alt="iPhone APPR">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div id="services-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>What we can do for you</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row service-row">

                <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/s-creative.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="service">
                    Mobile Application <br>
                    Design &amp; Development
                </p>
                <p class="desc">(iOS — Android — Windows)</p>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {max-width: 100%;}
#services-header{
background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/services-header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
color: #ffffff;
}

#services-header h1 {
font-size: 56px;
padding-top: 60px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 120%;
margin-bottom: .3em;
}

#services-header p {
font-size: 24px;
}

#services-content h1 {
font-size: 56px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
}
#services-content img {
display: block;
margin: 10px auto;
}
#services-content p.service {
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
}
#services-content p.service a{
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
color: #f93434;
cursor: pointer;
}
#services-content p.desc {
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
}
.service-row {
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
footer.services-page {
background: #000000;
padding: 20px 40px;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 300;
}

span.copyright {

}

span.footer-contact {
float: right;
}
span.footer-contact a {
margin-right: 30px;
color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: To the person that posted a comment, but removed it. I need the header section to contain the header content. The below content shouldn't be covered with that photo. please see screenshot [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/half.JPG)

Comment: The tutorial on `CSS Tricks` is pretty comprehensive and straightforward. What's your question?

Comment: Also, include all the relevant information into your question. We need to see your `HTML` markup and `CSS` styles.

Comment: I need to apply that full background on a `<div>` - not the entire HTML. The problem I'm facing is that on lower height browsers/screens - the content from that `div` goes "out of it" - see screenshot "reduced" in question. I'm not sure if I can help in clarifying this in any other way? If so, please just tell me. Thanks

Comment: So your requirement can't be fulfilled by the tutorial. That one is about a whole page background.

Comment: So you mean you want to see the full picture just in that div?

Comment: @AlexG - yes, with the same behavior as in the tut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Mozilla needed a `body {height:100%;}` definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accomplish the same as the CSS-Tricks example you have to do the same

```
html{
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/services-header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: OK, but I need to achieve the same, but on just a DIV. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok, then do that:  `background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/services-header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;` (in `#services-header` of course)

Comment: my content still runs out of that div at the bottom..any ideas?

Comment: You want the "What we can do for you" Section also inside the background div?

Comment: I want everything that is on the "full" screenshot inside that div. However, when I reduce the height of the browser, the "small" screenshot shows what happens. the iPhone image goes out of it on the bottom. Does that make sense? The "What we can do for you" needs to stay separated - it's own div without that background

Comment: Hmm, if I squish the window in jsfiddle the image stays where it should be and becomes smaller

Comment: Yeah exactly, But not in a real browser. I tried removing `style="height: 100%;"` from the `<div class="col-xs-12" >` - that fixed the overflow issue. However, now my background div doesn't cover the entire page in Mozilla, only Chrome. Any thoughts?

Comment: I get this [mozilla-full-screen](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3ygckm8t7bt91a8/AAA2oEWLDiqAOE5wmTWUp31va?dl=0) - the background div doesn't cover entire screen

Comment: Unfortunally I can't quite reproduze your issuse, I've tried it in my Chrome and Firefox, there is nothing out of the ordinary. Well, at least in jsfiddle

Comment: Strange. Basically, without that style definition, I get it good in Chrome, but Mozilla doesn't get a full screen div.

Comment: Sorry, here it is again. [moz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brkxb6ifkpxob45/moz.JPG?dl=0) and [chrome](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/chr.JPG)

Comment: No problem, but I'm not sure what could be the cause to this, I'm sorry. =/

Comment: OK @AlexG  - I appreciate the effort! :)

Comment: try this `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: this is in the answer already, as well as in the question `no-repeat center center fixed`